# Itemize bullets are squared when using sans serif Latin Modern

Tags: fonts, itemize, sans-serif, latin-modern, bullets

I noticed that if you use the Latin modern font, loading it with the appropriate package and you set the default family to sans-serif, the bullets of the `itemize` environment are squared rather than rounded.

Why this happens and how to avoid it? Here there is a MWE and two screenshots, the first on the left showing the squared bullets and the second on the right about the normal rounded bullets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Squared bullets]
[image: Normal rounded bullets]

EDIT: Seems that the problems starts when you write the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` line, because I've noticed that if you delete the this line and try to write the `itemize` environment putting it into a `{\sffamily }` environment, the bullets appear  in rounded shape (see below). Any idea about why this happens?

```
{\sffamily
   \begin{itemize}
   \item a
   \item b
   \end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that on my system.

Comment: @leandriis you don't get squares? I do (using TL19 frozen). It comes down to the `\familydefault` change.

Comment: @leandriis try to comment the `\usepackage{lmodern}` line, you'll see the bullets change their shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works.
Any idea about the second question? (I have edited my original question)

Comment: I think that`changing `\familydefault` has a wider extent that simply changing  the family. In the  article class, \labelitemi is defined as  `\textbullet`, and it is taken from the default font.

Comment: Ok thanks fort the answer :)

Comment: the bullet size in the solution answer is not of the same size as the original.

Comment: @user1850133: the question was about avoiding square bullets, so I didn't even think about checking this point. This being said, a simple way to obtain round bullets of the same size would probably be to use the enumitem key `font = lmodern`  (not tested,, though).